# How can i aggregate rows of a data.frame by name, summing the numeric value of the correspondent columns on R?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am an early user of Rstudio, and i have a quite simple problem, but unfortunately i am not able to solve it. 
I just want to aggregate rows of my data.frame by words contained on the first column of the df.
The data.frame is made by five columns: 
The first one is made by words;
the second, the third, the fourth, the fifth ones are made by numeric values.

for example if the data would be:

```
SecondWord  X Y Z Q
NO          1 2 2 1
NO          0 0 1 0
YES         1 1 1 1
```

i expect to see a result like:

```
SecondWord  X Y Z Q
NO          1 2 3 1
YES         1 1 1 1
```

How could i do?
i have tried to use the following method:

```
test <- read.csv2("test.csv")
df<-aggregate(.~Secondword,data=test, FUN = sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But the values were not the ones i expected to see. 
Thank you for your future helps and sorry for the "simple" question.

Comment: `aggregate(.~SecondWord, test, sum)` works for me. Print `test` once before you apply `aggregate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- test %>%
  group_by(SecondWord) %>%
  summarize_each(funs(sum))

df
# SecondWord     X     Y     Z     Q
#         NO     1     2     3     1
#        YES     1     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

[ddply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/ddply) should work as well.

For example, something like:

```
library(plyr)
grouped <- ddply(test, "Secondword", numcolwise(sum))
```

Comment: Generally, you should identify the packages used in the body of the question and refer to help files like `?ddply` rather than using a link that might break a few years from now.

Comment: Well, I expect Google still alive a few years from now. If it breaks, search for ddply there.